# list (mis?) comprehension in Python2.7 for rows and columns

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, list-comprehension

I've reviewed the documentation:
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html?highlight=list%20comprehension

But I'm having trouble with understanding list comprehension logic & syntax. In order to construct a list of grid values (row by column) relative to a height and width input (e.g. a 4 x 6 grid of zeros:
`[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]`)

this nested for-loop does the job:

```
h = 4
w = 6
grid_list = []
for row in xrange(h):
    grid_list.append(list())
    for col in xrange(w):
        grid_list[row].append(0)
```

...and I understand list comprehensions enough that I can do the same with two listcomp statements:

```
h = 4
w = 6
grid = [[] for row in xrange(h)]
grid = [[0 for col in xrange(w)] for nested_row_list in grid]
```

But, is there a single list comprehension statement that would accomplish the entire construction? Or is it that the `grid_list.append(list())` extends the range of the for-loop outside of what a list comprehension can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can simply do

```
grid = [[0 for col in xrange(w)] for row in xrange(h)]
```

Comment: :: f a c e p a l m :: ...overthink... thank you (i am only somewhat embarrassed)